# Web service scenario in BizTalk server

Tags: biztalk

I am new to BizTalk server and I want to know that is it possible to communicate with bizTalk like a web server? My scenario is like this.

I have a application in silverlight that will send request to biztalk (web service or http) with some parameter, biztalk will send that request to third party web service, third party web service will give response to Biztalk, this response will be sent back to my silverlight application.

Is this possible? if yes can anybody give me an article that help in creating this type of application.

Comment: Why do you need BizTalk for this as opposed to having your Silverlight app talk to either the target web service directly or through an intermediate web service?  Are you expecting the target web service to not return a response for a long time?

Answer (score 7):

Yes - Use the SOAP adapter and a web service port
[Service Station from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163464.aspx)

You will need to create an orchestration and a map (if the schema are different between the 2 services) to handle the actual passing of Messages between the 2 web services.
[First Steps in Orchestrations](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/biztalk/FootstepsInOrchestration.aspx)

[Creating Maps in BizTalk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms945741.aspx)

and a good guide and tutorial for Webservices  [here](http://blogs.digitaldeposit.net/saravana/post/2006/12/20/BizTalk-2006-SOAP-Adapter-(Web-Service-call)-in-Messaging-Only-Scenario.aspx)

Calling biztalk webservice from Silverlight 
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/06/14/calling-an-asmx-webservice-from-silverlight-use-a-static-port.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You can set up an HTTP Receive Port and handle straight XML messages from SilverLight and then pass back whatever message SilverLight requires (be sure to use a 2-Way Receive/Send Port).  The bigger question here is why?  Why not talk to the far end web service directly from SilverLight?  Is BizTalk adding any value here?  Are you including BizTalk as an abstractionlayer for future functionality?  Is BizTalk some how enriching the messages?

Answer (score 1):

My questions are the same as ChrisLoris.. Why use Biztalk here? If its just to call Service A and then B and deliver information back to the silverlight app, I would rather create acustom .net .dll to handle it. If you really want to have a workflow you can use WorkflowFoundation..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem. You need to install the certificate in the user store of the user under which biztalk host instance is running and also grant access to private key of the certificate using winhttpcertcfg tool.
1)Open the mmc using runas /user:<> mmc
and import the certificate into the user store.
2)winhttpcertcfg -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -s <> -a <>

These two steps should do the trick.